# getting comments per post of a page using FQL query

Tags: facebook-graph-api, facebook-javascript-sdk, facebook-fql

I am trying to get comments per post of a facebook page/group/profile following way -

```
SELECT fromid, username, text, time, post_id FROM comment WHERE post_id in (SELECT post_id  
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
    FROM page 
    WHERE name='joomla'
) limit 3)
```

but no data i see.how to write fql query for that plz help.also if i try to get post id seperately by -

```
SELECT post_id  
FROM stream 
WHERE source_id IN (
      SELECT page_id 
      FROM page 
      WHERE name='joomla'
)
```

it don't return anything coz page name specifying as 'joomla' not right but if i use name as 'coca-cola' things ok.so what is the correct way to get page_id by fql query ? i think for not getting page_id this way my first query not working. help experts...i did not find solution anywhere yet

Answer (score 2):

For your case, please don't do like that

```
WHERE source_id IN (
    SELECT page_id 
    FROM page 
    WHERE name='joomla'
)
```

You should do like that instead (http://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/?fql=%20SELECT%20name%2Cpage_id%20FROM%20page%20WHERE%20name%3D%22joomla%22)

```
 SELECT name,page_id FROM page WHERE name='joomla'
```

Extract the specific page id from this result, let's say the page_id is 139664469820, then you can do

```
SELECT fromid, username, text, time, post_id FROM comment WHERE post_id in (SELECT post_id FROM stream WHERE source_id='139664469820' LIMIT 25)
```

Comment: well that's not good idea to get all different id's of 'joomla' page then again how do i decide which is my page id exactly automatically? its also look like a sepearate fql query to call. i wanted better ways where all combined in one call.

Comment: Actually you only want to get the page='joomla' which was LIKED or CREATED by you already, right?

Comment: No my clients want to show any page/profile/group posts along with all comments.so it may be any page not only  liked or created one

Comment: All comments? Did you know how long it may take to load only one page? Try this https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer?fql=SELECT%20fromid%2C%20username%2C%20text%2C%20time%2C%20post_id%20FROM%20comment%20WHERE%20post_id%20in%20(SELECT%20post_id%20FROM%20stream%20WHERE%20source_id%3D'6815841748'%20LIMIT%2025)%0A

Comment: Why u think all comments! I will define limit.and all i am doing by fql query coz fb graph api dont return all comments per post for some pages

Comment: For your example, 'source_id IN()', is the known bug on http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/323944437691725/

Comment: that means i can only use one id under source_id IN().so i will use "WHERE source_id=34343434" for that i guess i  use graph api to get page id at first before running the query if there is no alternatives.